# Is there a reason to use Cordova instead of a basic Webview inside an existnig app?

Tags: android, cordova

Pretty much as the title says.

I developed a cordova app as a proof of concept, and the person I developed it for liked it and wants the look and feel of some parts of it in their existing app while I continue to work on the cordova app.

Is there any reason to use cordova in an existing native app vs just using a webview?  Does Cordova give you anything inside an existing native app that a webview does not?

Answer (score 1):

Cordova provides plugins, which are a bridge to execute native code using javascript.

Also, now you can use plugable webviews, which allow you to switch the default webview with another one (like crosswalk) but keeping the plugin compatibility.
But those webviews are also available without Cordova.

So, if you need the plugins, use Cordova, if you don't need them, use a regular webview.

But as you want to put it inside an existing app, the documentation to do it is out of date, so it's going to be a bit hard to do it.